# List of referenced entities appended to a node

Tags: 7, views, flags, entities

I have two content types: "project" and "task"
Using flag and with support of [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) + [flagging form](https://www.drupal.org/project/flagging_form), users can append very rapidly new "task" nodes to the current "project" node they are viewing.
The structure then is the following:

1. Node type 1 >> project
2. Node type 2 >> task
3. Flag >> task appended to project; actually is a "container" of an Entity
   Reference(with multiple value) field linked to task

My target is create with views, a list of appended "task" nodes and show that list in a block to the related "project" node.
I believe that I should use relationship + contextual filter, but I have no idea on how to achieve my needs.

Could you help me? Thank you all in advance!

Update on 13-01-2017 16:45:
Attached step by step after suggestion from pierostz. These steps were done before the configuration window uploaded at 15:00.
[image]

Update on 13-01-2017 15:00:
Attached contextual filter Nid after a first aattempt after suggestion from pierostz.
[image]

Comment: Looks like Drupal 7. Please tag your question with the right Drupal version.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view showing tasks nodes. In your view use these settings.

1. Add a relationship "Entity Reference: Referencing entity".
2. Add a contextual filter of "Content:nid" with the relationship you previously created as the selected option on the relationship select box. Also provide the default value from "Content ID from URL".

[image]

3. Create another contextual filter with "Content: References".
4. Choose what fields to show as you normally do in a view.

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you pierostz for you kind reply. I tried to follow your guide, but i stucked on point 2, since I cannot find how to put "with the relationship you previously created as the selected option on the relationship select box". I add a screenshot to my main question in order to let you see what I have here. Thank you again!

Comment: See my newly attached screenshot...the only reason you might not get the Relationship box is because you didn't create the relationship itself (Step 1). Also use the same method I do to provide the default value.

Comment: Dear pierostz, thank you very much again. I actually created the relationship (at list I am convinced to), but seems like that the relationship I've created is not available. Check the new attached images, I've tried to "Add a new relationship" "Entity Reference: Referencing entity", but then when I try to add Contextual Filter the supposed created relationship is not available, I am doing something wrong?

Comment: hm...I really can't see how this is not working for you...try creating a different relationship to see if you get the box...